# Update code on one google sheet without having to update on other sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I apologize if this is a very basic question but would appreciate if anyone could guide me on this. I have created some code for a set of Google Sheets Workbooks, 14 of them to be exact. But I have found that every time a person reports a problem with the code scripts and I can fix it on one the workbook projects I now have to go and fix it on the other 13 workbooks as well. Most of the times it is just a copy and paste from the fixed workbook to the other 13 workbook's script code which doesn't take much time but, as the number of users grows I may end up having to do this possibly even more times. Expected number of users is 105 by end of year. So I was wondering if there is a way I could have centralized code instead of having it on each workbook and having to do this over and over again.

Comment: You can use the Apps Script API to replace the code in a script file from a JSON string.  It's how I currently store backups of my code and restore my code if something gets lost or messed up some how.  Here's a [link](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/saverestore-script-with-json-files) you can take a look at.  I'm not trying to persuade you to use it.  It's a bit more code intensive over just using a library but there may come a time when you wished you hadn't decided to use libraries and You'll wish you knew about this alternative if you ever get to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed possible. Create the code, common to all spreadsheets in a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries). Then in the spreadsheets refer to the function(s) inside the library. On YouTube you can find a lot of tutorials that should get you started. Here's an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agWFuUMR6Vc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it seems like I have to keep development mode on all the sheets in order for them to propagate over. Otherwise I have to change the version number on each sheet too. Is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly how I do it. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I will start looking into the use of libraries.